# import pandas in visual studio(2022)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, visual-studio

My Environment in VS 2022 is Python 3.8 (same as the Python version installed on my system), I installed the pandas package using pip install pandas, and it said successfully installed. But when I import pandas I get the "import pandas could not be resolved from source" report.
any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Version mismatches problem:

First you need to make sure that the python3 interpreter version from terminal version is the same with your python version selection in VSCode.

1. Open terminal
2. Type 'python3'; you'll see your python version (Eg. version x)
3. Open your IDE VSCode
4. Open any/current folder that related to python project on IDE VSCode
5. Check your python version at the bottom right on IDE VSCode (Eg. version
   y)
6. Change or switch VSCode python version from (version y) to (version x)